# Where is the MIT/GNU scheme reference on threads?

Tags: scheme, lisp, sicp, mit-scheme

I've had a look here - [reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref.pdf). Also, looked at some other places but they turned out to be other scheme dialects, which means the functions there are not necessarily present in MIT/GNU scheme.

I obviously know that there must be thread related procedures since things like `create-thread` or `current-thread` or `thread-dead` works.
Can anyone point to the reference for threads. I'm using the Release 9.2 of MIT/GNU Scheme.

Answer (score 2):

There are not many volunteers who are working for mit-scheme, in general they are alumni of EECS of MIT, where they learned exactly how mit-scheme was implemented, and they are the only competent ones to understand it; this is why it is the best to ask at `mit-scheme-devel@gnu.org` and somebody will surely answer you some specific questions.  Apart from the documentation from `src/compiler/documentation`  and from [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/), there is no other documentation.

Using `git log | less` and searching for `thread` also returns nothing suggestive.

[Here](http://web.mit.edu/benmv/6.001/www/threads.txt) is the only available documentation and [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/mit-scheme-devel/2019-04/msg00001.html) is asked the same question.  He surely received a private answer.

Comment: FWIW The problem in the mail thread wasn't about threads. The definition of `thunk` was `(define (thunk x) (lambda () x))` which is incorrect. A macro is needed to implement `thunk`.

Comment: @soegaard I am not sure about what you say, maybe he passes x as (lambda() _something_) and by evaluating the thunk he gets x as another thunk.  There is no need of macro, but the focus of that mail is about the inexistence of docs.

Comment: My point was that threads in MIT Scheme works. The example in the post linked to gives the impression there were a problem. The problem was a faulty test. The poster defined `thunk` as `(define (thunk x) (lambda () x))` and then called it as `(thunk expr)` but missed that the evaluation of `expr` isn't delayed.

Comment: @soegaard indeed, he was wrong about the delayed operation, but usually a delayed operation can be implemented without a macro, it can -- by convention -- be nested in a thunk and forced when it's value is needed, and this happens without the use of macros.  There is also the case when lazy evaluation is available by default, where it's evaluated by need.